# Как сделать дерево иерархии в js

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend

В общем, js учу пару дней и стоит задача сделать дерево. 
Суть: на вход приходят 2 массива, которые в себе содержат объекты. Нужно из 2ого массива добавить в первый все узлы(объект), которые отсутствуют. Т.е. если id одинаковый, то добавлять узел не нужно. Ниже пример массивов.

```
var data1 = [ 
            {
            id: '1',
            child: [
                {
                id: '2',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '3',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '4',
                child: [
                    {
                        id: '5',
                        child: []
                    }
                ]    
                }
            ]
        }
    ]; 


    var data2 = [ 
            {
            id: '1',
            child: [
                {
                id: '2',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '3',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '4',
                child: [
                    {
                        id: '5',
                        child: [
                            {
                                id: '6',
                                child: [
                                    {
                                        id: '7',
                                        child: [
                                            {
                                                id: '8',
                                                child: []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]    
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Простенькие, но мне нужно понять суть, как пройтись, чтобы в 1ый, добавить узлы 2ого. Находил только с использованием тегов, а здесь прекрасное в том, что всё в массиве.

В общем, направьте в правильное русло, как это замутить.

Comment: Ну судя по тому, как стоит задача, то уже на первой итерации будет выход. Так как во втором массиве имеется узел с id=1 таким же как и в первом

Comment: @sepgg ну так а на 4 узле не всех элементов хватает. Как вообще можно пройти дерево?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let compare=(old,kid)=>{
    kid.forEach(obj=>{
    if(old.every(v=>{
      if(obj.id!==v.id) return true
      if(obj.child.length) 
        if(v.child.length) compare(v.child,obj.child)
        else v.child=obj.child
    })) old.push(obj)
  })
}
compare(data1,data2)
```

Если применить рекурсию, то логика получается довольно простой:

- поочерёдно брать объекты второго массива и сравнивать с каждым объектом первого массива.
- если не было ни одного совпадения по свойству "id", то значит объект целиком уникален и его можно добавить к первому массиву со всеми его детьми.
- Если было найдено совпадение, то проверяем, есть ли объекты в массиве с детьми у совпадающего объекта из второго массива. Если их нет, то он нас больше не интересует.
- Если дети есть, а также они есть и у совпавшего объекта из первого массива, то создаём новую ветку рекурсии и проводим сравнение массивов с детьми.
- Если у объекта из первого массива детей не оказалось, значит все дети объекта из второго массива точно окажутся уникальными, просто сваливаем их всех объекту из первого массива.

Рабочий пример:

```js
var data1 = [
            {
            id: '1',
            child: [
                {
                id: '2',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '3',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '4',
                child: [
                    {
                        id: '5',
                        child: []
                    }
                ]    
                }
            ]
        }]; 


    var data2 = [
            {
            id: '1',
            child: [
                {
                id: '2',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '3',
                child: []
                },

                {
                id: '4',
                child: [
                    {
                        id: '5',
                        child: [
                            {
                                id: '6',
                                child: [
                                    {
                                        id: '7',
                                        child: [
                                            {
                                                id: '8',
                                                child: []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]    
                }
            ]
        }];
let compare=(old,kid)=>{
    kid.forEach(obj=>{
    if(old.every(v=>{
        if(obj.id!==v.id) return true
      if(obj.child.length) 
        if(v.child.length) compare(v.child,obj.child)
        else v.child=obj.child
    })) old.push(obj)
  })
}
compare(data1,data2)
console.log(data1)
```

P.S. Только не понял зачем у вас в структуре данных был массив содержащий в себе ещё один единственный массив, я убрал эту абстракцию.

Comment: Описка, я уже заметил, сейчас подправлю)

Comment: Разобрался, действительно,  работает как нужно и всё понятно, спасибо :)

Comment: @KeyJibo Пожалуйста, рад помочь :3